# strcmp fails when comparing two words that are supposed to be the same

Tags: c, string, compare

So I have a list of words, let's call them

```
words = {"red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange"}
```

and then I have a string that I read from `stdin`, I parse this string using the following code

```
char *token; 
token = strtok(string," ");
```

then I compare the new token to the list of words in a for loop using

```
strcmp(token,words[i]);
```

Now this only works if my input is followed by at least a space, for example,

`"blue hello"` or `"blue "`, will evaluate to the words matching since token will equal `"blue"` but if my input is just `"blue"` the token is `""` and I cannot compare the two.

Now my workaround included running `isblank()` on the string and only using stroke if there was a empty space in the string and if there wasn't an empty space then I just compare the string itself since I know its only one word using the following

```
strcmp(string, words[I])
```

but this also results in `strcmp` failing and not being able to compare the two string together. I don't really know where else to go with this but if someone could maybe see my mistake in my explanation then I would greatly appreciate being corrected and shown my mistakes. I would love to post more code but this has to do with school so I cannot post more within possibly getting into trouble. If you would like more of an explanation I would be happy to explain more.

Comment: Rather than describe code with "then I have a string that I read from stdin", post the code.

Comment: @chux as I mentioned, I can't post too much of the code since this is for school, I can guarantee you that I read it correctly since this is something I have done many times.

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve].  Then edit your question to be a mcve.

Comment: ... or use your debugger and see why string != words[i].  It's probably something like including \r \n characters in string.

Comment: I suspect you have a newline character in your string.

Comment: Please expalin why working for school means that you cannot show your code? It is of course not that you are forbidden to use StackOverflow help and therefor do not want to risk being found out by your teacher, is it?

Comment: @Yunnosch we are allowed to post on stack overflow but our professors are very picking about what is considered an academic offence and generally do not approve of us showing our code around, they prefer we ask more "theory" based questions I guess so I thought this would be more appropriate for the situation then posting my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading from `stdin` with `fgets`, then most probably a new line is
in stored in your `string` variable.

You can clear the newline with

```
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0;
```

after the `fgets` or you can add `\n` to the list of delimiters when using
`strtok`:

```
char *token; 
token = strtok(string, " \n");
```

`strtok` would in this case use an empty space **and** the new line as
delimiters, thus the newline does not appear in `token`.

Comment: That's what I forgot about thank you so much. once I accounted for the \n my code started working perfectly fine.